# Printing Our Array Data

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP, Codeigniter: my array, $phoneList, contains the following:

```
Array
(
    [name] => One, Are
    [telephonenumber] => 555.222.1111
)

Array
(
    [name] => Two, Are
    [telephonenumber] => 555.222.2222
)

Array
(
    [name] => Three, Are
    [telephonenumber] => 555.222.3333
)
```

How do I list each name out? Each number out? Am I right in saying my array contains three different Arrays? And is that normal, for an array to contain arrays?

When I do a print_r($phoneList), I get the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => One, Are [telephonenumber] => 555.222.1111 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Two, Are [telephonenumber] => 555.222.2222 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Three, Are [telephonenumber] => 555.222.3333 ) )
```

Comment: Having an array of arrays ("multidimensional array") is perfectly allowable, common, and useful.

Comment: @Wiseguy... I agree, but I couldn't seem to print out each name or each number... when I looped through the arrays, using `foreach ( $phoneList as $row ) {` it only printed the first name, not the other two.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure what your question was. What was the exact code you used in that `foreach` loop?

Comment: I was being stupid! Kolink was correct, I was doing `echo $row->name instead of echo $row['name']`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to use [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) to loop through them. Something like this:

```
foreach($data as $arr) { // assuming $data is the variable that has all this in
    echo $arr['name'].": ".$arr['telephonenumber']."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://codepad.org/iY3cfT6B) is the solution. [Foreach](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/foreach.php) is the easiest approach.

Answer (score 1):

It's completely normal to have an array of arrays (in this case an array of associative arrays). They can be written like so:

```
$arrayofarray = array(array('name' => 'aname', 'phone'=>'22233344444'), array('name' => 'bobble', 'phone'=>'5552223333'));
print_r($arrayofarray);
```

and you should be able to print out the content in this way:

```
foreach ($arrayofarray as $arr){
    print $arr['name']."\n";
    print $arr['phone']."\n";
}
```

If you want to know what terms are set in each associative array you can use array_keys() to return them (as a simple array). For example:

```
foreach ($arrayofarray as $arr){
    $setterms=array_keys($arr);
    foreach ($setterms as $aterm){
            print "$aterm -> ".$arr[$aterm]."\n";
    }
}
```